# Drupal 7 : I want "Access Denied on Node but Title listing in view"

Tags: users

I used [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) for restricting content of particular content type.

Anonymous user can't see Node and get Access Denied But want to listing of those restricted node's title to Anonymous user.
I searched and found [premium content](http://drupal.org/project/premium_content) module but not found way to use it.

What I want,When Anonymous go:
On node == Access Denied,
On View (listing Title) == can see Title.

kindly help me for premium content **OR any other Solution**.

Answer (score 1):

Using view you can achieve this functionality,

In you view go to Query settings in others tab, In the popup select **Disable SQL rewriting**

This is what views says about this option

```
Disabling SQL rewriting will disable node_access checks as well as other
modules that implement hook_query_alter().
```

Then Content access will not able to alter this query, so your users who don't have permission to view the particular content type also can see the views results

While When they are trying to access the node, on that time content access will not allow them to see that node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I m not getting Query setting tab. There is a tab SETTINGS and there is one checkbox "Show the SQL query". I m not seeing the option Disable Sql rewriting. May i get url for that setting..

Comment: May be that m not using latest version of view.

Comment: Go and edit your view, In the view edit page you can find the "Query settings" under the Advanced options section.

Comment: Thanks mathan..actually i was not using views 3 thats y not getting "Query settings". now resolved

Comment: Does that mean, now you updated the views to 3 and this working properly?